# Delete data from table that is not reorganized (in db2)

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a table that needs to be reorganised using the reorg command in DB@, However due to large size of the table, I am unable to do so. So I plan to  delete entire data from the table and then do any reorg if required..

Is there any possible way for doing so?

I already used

```
DELETE FROM TABLE-NAME
```

and

```
TRUNCATE TABLE SCHAME-NAME.TABLE-NAME IMMEDIATE
```

But both the above queries aren't  working and are giving the following error which is the one for reorg.

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, SQLERRMC=7;DB2ADMIN.CERTIFICATE_TAB, DRIVER=3.50.152
>       SQLState:  57016
>       ErrorCode: -668

Comment: If you don't want to run `REORG`, your only other option is to drop and re-create the table.

Comment: I can't drop the existing table. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Why can't you drop it? It's no different from truncating it, is it now?

Comment: Actually I don't have the appropriate privilages to CREATE the new table.

Comment: ...but you can _drop_ it?